# @Override - can Override all Methods of interface except of one

Tags: java, overriding

Im implementing an Interface. I use `@Override` on all the methods, no Problem there. Except for one Method.

I get Error only for this method, that it doesn't really override a supertype,
When I take the annotation away, it would compile, but than of course, the App who import the interface (which is being initialized by the interface implementation - maven + swing) has Problem recognizing this method (but not all the rest). What could be the reason? May be because the return type is complex?
**Well, I added more information:**
interface:

```
package de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.kurznachrichten;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public interface ShortMessageService {

    Long createMessage(String userName, String message, String topic);

    Long respondToMessage(String userName, String message, Long predecessor);

    void deleteMessage(String userName, Long messageId) throws AuthorizationException;

    void createTopic(String userName, String topic);

    Set<String> getTopics();

    List<List<Message>> getMessageByTopic(String topic, Date since);

    void createUser(String userName, String city);

    void deleteUser(String userName);

    Set<User> getUsers(); 

}
```

I do indeed have two different classes, MeinMessage that implements Message. 
The infterface is the in the package as Message. The implementation import package of MeinMessage. But I got this issue with those father - child classes in other methods of this Interface, and no problem there.

in Implementation:

```
package de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.kurznachrichtenImpl;

import de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.kurznachrichten.*;
import de.htw_berlin.aStudent.model.*;

import de.htw_berlin.aStudent.repository.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Set;
import de.htw_berlin.aStudent.repository.MeinAuthorizationException;   
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.annotation.Resource;


@Service("smsImpl")
public class ShortMessageServiceImpl implements ShortMessageService{


    @Autowired
    MeinUserRepository meinUserRepository;

    @Autowired
    MeinMessageRepository meinMessageRepository;

    @Autowired
    TopicRepository topicRepository;

    public ShortMessageServiceImpl(){

    }

    @Override 
    @Transactional
    public List<List<Message>> getMessageByTopic(String topic, Date since){

        if(topic == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Given parameter can not point on NULL");    

        Topic refTopic = topicRepository.getTopicByString(topic);
        if(refTopic == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Topic does not exist");

            List<MeinMessage> messagesOfTopic = new ArrayList(refTopic.getMessages());
            List<List<Message>> result = new ArrayList<List<Message>>();


            for(MeinMessage var : messagesOfTopic){ //for 1

                if(var.isOrigin()){
                    List<Message> temp = new ArrayList<Message>();
                    temp.add(var);
                    result.add(temp);
                }
                else{
                    Long predecessor = var.getPredecessor();
                    for(List<Message> chain: result)
                        if(chain.get(0).getMessageId() == predecessor)
                            chain.add(var);
                }
            }

        return result;
    }
```

All other methods of the interface are implemented with no problem.
When I take it away I get:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getMessageByTopic(java.lang.String,java.util.Date)
  location: variable ms1 of type de.htw_berlin.f4.ai.kbe.kurznachrichten.ShortMessageService
```

It couldn't be the imports. All other method of ShortMessageService, which I implement with @Override in ShortMessageServiceImpl I can ran with no Problem from App.

Comment: Is the `Message` class the *same* class in both interface and your implementation? Check that the two import statements name the same fully qualified class name.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the correct `List` and `Message` classes in both cases?

Comment: Show us only the snippet that's obviously correct and we're just guessing too...?!  Where's the interface and class declaration and the imports?

Comment: This may be a good case for constructing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Almost certainly, doing so will reveal the problem - there will be something that cannot be simplified without fixing it.

Comment: Another Information which may be important: This method was out commentd (I took it out for a while) in both interface and Implementation. But when I put it in again, I used: 
mvn clean   
mvn install so the dependensy will be correct. Could it be that the implementation still reads a not updated jar?

Comment: Maven has nothing to do with which `import` directives you have in your source code...